# Google Map InfoBar

Tags: google-maps

hi am using Google map in my project like store locator. there are 2 pages where one selects the store in first and page and the map is populated in second page now i want to display selected one on load of page by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show a map with a marker to locate the selected store then here are the [demos](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_simple_v3)  create a logic to check which store is selected the redirect to another page and call the function with parameter that sets the center on users selected store